# Algorithm to group items according to simple rules

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'd like some help to find the good algorithm for a problem but I can't even figure out how to abstract this problem so I'll write this question as en example of what I want.

Say I have a list of items of 2 types (**A** and **B**) which all have a value. The list looks like this :

1. A1 : 10
2. B1 : 11
3. A2 : 9
4. B2 : 6
5. B3 : 4

My problem is that I want to make as many groups of items as possible for the following rules :

- there must be at least 1 type **A** item and 1 type **B** item
- the sum of the values of each group must be at least 20

The output of the algorithm should be :

2 Groups found :

- Group 1 contains A1, B2 and B3
- Group 2 contains A2 and B1

Parameters of the problem may vary :

- this list itself of course (number of items, values, ...)
- the number of item types (from 1 to a lot)
- the number of items required per type (I may want at least 2 items from A and 3 items from B)
- the minimum required value sum

I'm almost sure such algorithm exist, it makes me think of the Knapsack problem but I actually don't even know what to search.

---

**Update: here are the algorithms I made to solve this problem to help you better understand my need.**

---

**Algorithm 1**

This algorithm just extracts required items in the order to reach the number of required items of each type and to reach the minimum sum.

1. Take the first available item of type A
2. Take the first available item of type B
3. Take more items of any type to reach total of 20 if necessary
4. If all required items and sum are reached, mark items as not available and return the first group
5. Loop until no more group can be made

This algorithm depends on the order of the list and returns a single group :

- Group 1 contains A1 and B1

It's very fast but it's not giving me the result I want.

---

**Algorithm 2**

This algorithm computes all possible ordering of the original list and executes Algorithm 1 on all the possibilities.

Then it takes the maximum number of groups out of the result and returns the first possibility with that number of groups.

The output is what I expect :

2 Groups found :

- Group 1 contains A1, B2 and B3
- Group 2 contains A2 and B1

The problem is that it has an exponential complexity, it's fast with 5 items (120 possibilities) but slow with 10 (3628800 possibilities).

---

**What I need is an algorithm to get the result from algorithm 2 but faster, I need a heuristic approach but... How ?**

Comment: what is the requirement which rejects solution where all items are in one group?

Comment: The goal is to have as many groups as possible.

Comment: how many items can we expect? How many groups could be made? How big can the values be?

Comment: @juvian We generally expect between 1 and 50 items, there is no limit to the number of groups that can be made and values may vary between 1 and 500.

Comment: @JimMischel The expected output is the groups of items (in my example 2 groups: A1+B2+B3 and A2+B1). My example is a sample input and output :)

Comment: This sounds more like a [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) with additional constraints.

Comment: @JimMischel if it can help, see the items as products and the groups as commercial offers triggers. The goal is to trigger as many offers as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It can easily be solved by a mathematical constraint solver:

Let's use following terms:

- @A = number of items with category A
- @B = number of items with category B
- n = min(@A, @B)
- G_j =    sum for i = 0 to @A of ( α_j_i * A_i) + sum for i=0 to @B of ( β_j_i * B_i )

Then the following equations must hold in order to have a valid solution:

- G_j is either 0 OR G_j is larger than 20
- min(α_j_0 ... α_j_@A ... β_j_0 ... β_j_@B) is either 0 or 1
- sum(α_0_0 ... α_0_n) is 1 (each A is used once)
- sum(β_0_0 ... β_0_n) is 1 (each B is used once)

And then we simply maximize

T = sum for i = 0 to n of 2 ^ G_i - 1

Which will add a 0 for each empty group, and a larger value for each non-empty group.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't understand this.

Comment: My proposed solution turns your problem  into a problem that can easily be solved by a constraint solver. Constraint solvers can typically handle only rudimentary mathematical equations and logical operators.

Comment: What α_j_i and β_j_i are ?

Comment: variables that denote how many times an item (indexed with j) is used in a group (indexed with i).

Comment: I believe this algorithm won't help, I edited my question to better reflect that the goal of the algorithm is to find groups of items, not the sum of their values. Also, I'd like to find the best possible groups, in my example, Algorithm 1 takes items in the order and can only find 1 group, which is my problem. Algorithm 2 is working but it is brute force so it's very slow with more items...

Comment: You can easily retrieve the exact groups by querying the values of α_i_j and β_i_j. The solver will optimize for the number of groups, but to express this mathematically (with the given variables), I used a somewhat non-trivial formula.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mathematical solvers, could you provide a working example with a solver (in .NET) or even better an algorithm ?